# PowerBI Histogram with Dynamic Bins Based on Variable

Tags: powerbi, statistics, visualization, histogram

Imagine you have the following dataset in PowerBI:

```
Date        Temperature (Deg C)  City 
10/01/01    5                    London
10/01/01    15                   Lisbon
10/01/01    10                   Paris
10/01/02    7                    London
10/01/02    12                   Lisbon
10/01/02    8                    Paris
...         ...                  ...
```

You want to create a histogram visual with in PowerBI with City as a variable in a Slicer (Filter). So as you change the city, you see the temperature distribution for that city on the histogram. **However**, you want to the bin size to change dynamically as you change city. Otherwise you end up with a situation where some histograms have all data in one bin etc.

From the time I have spent trying to figure this out (what seems like a critical feature missing), it seems like I can only fix the size of the bins or the number of bins (and the bin size being fixed also as a result) across all variable changes (i.e. fixed for different City values) by creating a group (bin) field.

Any insight into how this could be done would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: https://www.daxpatterns.com/dynamic-segmentation/

Comment: Can you provide more input data ?